# dialog box creation in windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am running the following to create a dialog box in windows. when I run it I get the follwoing error:

```
                   Error 1 error C2065: 'IDD_DLGFIRST' : undeclared identifier
```

Here is the code:

```
                 HWND hWnd;
                LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

           INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
     {
                  DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLGFIRST),
                  hWnd, reinterpret_cast<DLGPROC>(DlgProc));

               return FALSE;
               }

       LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
             {
           switch(Msg)
             {
               case WM_INITDIALOG:
                              return TRUE;

                 case WM_COMMAND:
               switch(wParam)
             {
               case IDOK:
                       EndDialog(hWndDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;
             }
                break;
              }

               return FALSE;
     }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I do know that there are resource files but I haven't understood that very well.
could someone help me out to resolve this error please.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the symbol both in the resource file,  as well as the file that calls MAKEINTRESOURCE.  usually it's done via a common header file that you `#include`  in both places (for instance `#include resource.h` in resource.rc and main.cpp).

And  in the `resource.h`  you put `#define IDD_DLGFIRST 1` for example.  Just make sure that the number is unique across resources.

**EDIT:**

As an example:

*resource.h*

```
#define IDD_DLGFIRST 1001
#define IDC_STATIC   1002
```

*yourapp.rc*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

IDD_DLGFIRST DIALOGEX 0, 0, 170, 62
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "My dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "My first dialog box, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
END
```

*yourapp.cpp*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
           LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  //Open dialog box
  DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLGFIRST), HWND_DESKTOP, DlgProc);
  return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
       switch(Msg)
       {
       case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return TRUE;
            break;  //Don't forget about the break;
       case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(wParam)
            {
                case IDOK:
                    EndDialog(hWndDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;
            }
            break;
       }
}
```

Comment: @ W.B, as you mentioned,I do not need the separate resource file then?

Comment: just define IDD_DLGFIRST in resource.h?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid - if you already have a resource file then you don't need to create another one. Just add `define IDD_DLGFIRST` to `resource.h`, which you have included in both `.rc` and `.cpp` files. That's because each resource needs to have its numer identifier. So when you type just IDD_DLGFIRST without defining what it means, the compiler does not know, which resource to get.

Comment: ok sorry but I need a little more help,in the resource.rc file,I get the following error:Error 1 error RC2104 : undefined keyword or key name: DS_SETFONT,can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid - sorry, forgot to include `windows.h` in the resource file as well. Fixed.

Comment: ,but I've included that in the cpp file,shouldn't it do the trick?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid - no, because the resource file has no knowledge of your cpp file. Why don't you check though?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid - Ok, I've altered the example for it to work as it is, which is without creating main window of the application. I've checked and it compiles and runs. Try it now.

Comment: @ W.B,Thank you so much,I finally got the dialog box:)